# Very wide equation ruins consecutive side edges

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath, width

I've just created a set of equations in matrix form which looks fine. It also seems to fit in the space of my document, but in the following space after the equation, the side edge is suddenly gone, i.e. the text starts further on the left than it should. This remains wrong for the rest of the document.

I have to mention that I want to label this equation on the right to keep consistent. Maybe a solution would be to reduce the space b/w the equation and the label on the right, if that's possible. `\split`is no option here, because it doesn't look good in vector form.

edit: found out the issue. The text looks bad the way it is, but it in the correct position as pointed out in the answers. If you don't want to split you can only change the font it seems.

Here is a minimal example to illustrate the issue.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=4.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
a1 + a3 \\
a2 + a4\\
a3 + a2\\
a4 + a1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
b1 \\
b2 \\
b3 \\
b4
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
\theta & \theta  & \theta  & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta  \\
\theta  & \theta  & \theta  & \theta & \theta & \theta  & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta \\
\theta  & \theta  & \theta  & \theta  & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta  \\
\theta  & \theta  & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta & \theta 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c1 + 4352523523523532 \\
c2 + 4352523523523532\\
c3 + 4352523523523532\\
c4 + 4352523523523532
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
x1 \\
x2 \\
x3 \\
x4
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}
fgdgdfgfdgfdg dfgf fdg fdg dfgfdg dfg dfg fdgfdgdfg 
df gdfg fdfg fdg dfg fdg fdg df fdg dfg fdg
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which side edge are you talking about? I do not see anything wrong.

Comment: The text in your example is set to the specified margins (and would be the same if the equation were not there) in what way do you think it's wrong?

Comment: The edited example is a different issue altogether and doesn't match the description that the equation "fit in the space" as latex warns, the new equation is much too wide: `Overfull \hbox (118.74335pt too wide) detected at line 43` Although as in the original example the margins of the following text are unaffected by the equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text is set to the specified margins, which matches the text before the equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}


\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X


\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
a1 + a3 \\
a2 + a4\\
a3 + a2\\
a4 + a1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
b1 \\
b2 \\
b3 \\
b4
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
\theta & \theta  & \theta  & \theta  \\
\theta  & \theta  & \theta  & \theta  \\
\theta  & \theta  & \theta  & \theta   \\
\theta  & \theta  & \theta & \theta 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c1 \\
c2 \\
c3 \\
c4
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
x1 \\
x2 \\
x3 \\
x4
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}
fgdgdfgfdgfdg dfgf fdg fdg dfgfdg dfg dfg fdgfdgdfg 
df gdfg fdfg fdg dfg fdg fdg df fdg dfg fdg
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I am still learning it. If you could tell me a way how to check quickly if my side edges are still correct, that would be great.

Comment: @TomM, sorry I have no idea what you mean by "still correct". They don't change and are as you set them in the preamble with `\geometry`. Whether they are correct or not for your use I can not say.

Comment: I meant if you could show me how to measure the distance from the left. I mean you must have done it to claim they are correct. I see that you are correct because the text looks fine now, but I am still curious how to measure the exact distance.

Comment: @TomM I didn't measure anything, I made the initial comment without seeing anything either, just observing that your document had no code that could change the margins. I mainly made this an answer to make it easier to include a picture to show you that the left margin is the same before and after the equation despite what you wrote in the question.